# Running MTGArena on MacBook Pro using Wine and DXVK

Tags: install, games, x11, wine, xquartz

I have recently installed `wine` for the first time on my MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2011 running OSX 10.13.6 with OpenGL 16.7.4 and OpenCL 2.8.24) in order to play [MTGArena](https://magic.wizards.com/en/mtgarena)... unfortunately it doesn't work. I know that there are plenty of discussions around the web about this game, but none of what I've found solved my problem.
Here is what I've done:

1) Installed XQuartz 2.7.11 downloading the .pkg installer directly from the [homepage](https://www.xquartz.org/index.html) and temporary disabled Gatekeeper.

2) Installed Wine-devel 3.18 downloading the executable directly from the [homepage](https://www.winehq.org/).

3) Opened `Wine Devel.app` and run `wine MTGAInstaller.exe`. The installation went fine except that text inside the installation window was replaced by black rectangles (this is a common and uninfluential issue according to many posts around the web).

4) Closed the installer and launched `wine MtgaLauncher.exe` which fails with the following output (but I did not worry since also this is a known problem).

```
0025:err:ntoskrnl:IoCreateDriver failed to insert driver L"\\Driver\\WineHID" in tree
0025:err:ntoskrnl:IoCreateDriver failed to insert driver L"\\Driver\\WineHID" in tree
0025:err:ntoskrnl:IoCreateDriver failed to insert driver L"\\Driver\\WineHID" in tree
0025:err:ntoskrnl:IoCreateDriver failed to insert driver L"\\Driver\\WineHID" in tree
Can't find custom attr constructor image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Wizards of the Coast\MTGA\MtgaLauncher.exe mtoken: 0x0a00000c due to: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. assembly:PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 type:<unknown type> member:<none>

Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
  at MtgaLauncher.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <64953789a04047c4878c1a73afbf65a0>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
  at MtgaLauncher.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <64953789a04047c4878c1a73afbf65a0>:0
```

5) Hence I tried `wine MTGA.exe` which opens a window reporting an error about DirectX 11

[image: error about DirectX 11]

and prints the following output inside the terminal

```
0025:err:ntoskrnl:IoCreateDriver failed to insert driver L"\\Driver\\WineHID" in tree
0025:err:ntoskrnl:IoCreateDriver failed to insert driver L"\\Driver\\WineHID" in tree
0025:err:ntoskrnl:IoCreateDriver failed to insert driver L"\\Driver\\WineHID" in tree
0025:err:ntoskrnl:IoCreateDriver failed to insert driver L"\\Driver\\WineHID" in tree
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.60.1/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:49: Error: unsupported compressor 8
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.60.1/Libraries/CompressData/CompressData.c:353: Error: Unknown compression scheme encountered for file '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/Exceptions.plist'
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.60.1/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:49: Error: unsupported compressor 8
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.60.1/Libraries/CompressData/CompressData.c:353: Error: Unknown compression scheme encountered for file '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library/AppExceptions.bundle/Exceptions.plist'
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({5eec90ab-c022-44b2-a5dd-fd716a222a15}, 0x1dd1123, 0x2169dc0, 0x2169dd8) stub.
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 0x215a898, 43) stub
Mono path[0] = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Wizards of the Coast/MTGA/MTGA_Data/Managed'
Mono config path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Wizards of the Coast/MTGA/MonoBleedingEdge/etc'
0009:fixme:winsock:set_dont_fragment IP_DONTFRAGMENT for IPv6 not supported in this platform
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f688,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW (L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY1",0,0x32f688,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),1,0x32f688,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0x1004a, 0x27708f0): stub
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f600,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:dxgi:DXGID3D10CreateDevice Ignoring flags 0x1.
0009:fixme:winediag:wined3d_select_feature_level None of the requested D3D feature levels is supported on this GPU with the current shader backend.
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f530,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:d3d11:D3D11CreateDevice WARP driver not implemented, falling back to hardware.
0009:fixme:dxgi:DXGID3D10CreateDevice Ignoring flags 0x1.
0009:fixme:winediag:wined3d_select_feature_level None of the requested D3D feature levels is supported on this GPU with the current shader backend.
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f620,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:dxgi:DXGID3D10CreateDevice Ignoring flags 0x1.
0009:fixme:winediag:wined3d_select_feature_level None of the requested D3D feature levels is supported on this GPU with the current shader backend.
0009:fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f540,0x00000000), stub!
0009:fixme:d3d11:D3D11CreateDevice WARP driver not implemented, falling back to hardware.
0009:fixme:dxgi:DXGID3D10CreateDevice Ignoring flags 0x1.
0009:fixme:winediag:wined3d_select_feature_level None of the requested D3D feature levels is supported on this GPU with the current shader backend.
```

6) Now I'm lost!

I know nothing about DirectX and graphic libraries in general, so I really can't imagine where to start trying solve this issue (for example, do I have to install DirectX inside a `WINEPREFIX` before installing MTGArena? How? I suppose DirectX are not installed by default on my Mac since it's a proprietary Microsoft piece of software - if ever it is possible to installed them on Mac).

Googling around I've found some people talking about Vulkan libraries and DXVK but I'm unsure how to procede: should I install them on my Mac or inside Wine? Does Vulkan libraries replace some core piece of MacOS? How to make Wine aware of Vulkan?

Any help? Thank you!

P.S.:

- Which Wine version (devel or staging) is preferable for MTGArena?
- Is it better to install XQuartz and Wine from .pkg installer or use MacPort to install them? (I'm not a `brew` guy, so that's not an option).
- Does XQuartz replace some native part of MacOS or it's a software that only gets executed by Wine when needed?

I hope this is the proper place to ask this question.

**UPDATE**

I've found that installing `winetricks` and running

```
./winetricks d3dx11_43 dxvk vulkanrt
```

the command `wine MTGA.exe` manage to launch the game

[image]

but then I get this

[image]

The content of the "show details" button outputs the following

```
Unhandled exception: unimplemented function vulkan-1.dll.vkGetInstanceProcAddr called in 32-bit code (0x7bc4c488).
Register dump:
 CS:001b SS:0023 DS:0023 ES:0023 FS:1007 GS:000f
 EIP:7bc4c488 ESP:0032f6c8 EBP:0032f72c EFLAGS:00000202(   - --  I   - - - )
 EAX:6f5b45aa EBX:03fd6e00 ECX:6f5b4598 EDX:6f448e60
 ESI:0032f6d4 EDI:0032f7a8
Stack dump:
0x0032f6c8:  0032f6e8 4872ea23 03fd6e00 80000100
0x0032f6d8:  00000001 00000000 7bc4c488 00000002
0x0032f6e8:  6f5b4598 6f5b45aa 03fd6de0 03fd7029
0x0032f6f8:  00000008 6f5546f4 0032f7a8 00000010
0x0032f708:  0032f738 4872ea97 03fd0000 00000000
0x0032f718:  00000010 03fd6de0 03fd6e52 03fd6fea
7fa200: sel=3fd1007 base=7ffc0000 limit=00000fff 32-bit rw-
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7bc4c488 stub_entry_point+0x48() in ntdll (0x0032f72c)
  1 0x03fc001e (0x0032f958)
  2 0x6f4050e9 in dxgi (+0x50e8) (0x0032f9b4)
  3 0x6f405ce2 in dxgi (+0x5ce1) (0x0032fce8)
  4 0x108dc575 in unityplayer (+0x8dc574) (0x0032fd08)
  5 0x1045ce6f in unityplayer (+0x45ce6e) (0x0032fd20)
  6 0x1045e670 in unityplayer (+0x45e66f) (0x0032fd90)
  7 0x103bb1a5 in unityplayer (+0x3bb1a4) (0x0032fdd8)
  8 0x108d1b3a in unityplayer (+0x8d1b39) (0x0032fea0)
  9 0x108d22f5 in unityplayer (+0x8d22f4) (0x0032febc)
  10 0x00401015 in mtga (+0x1014) (0x0032fed4)
  11 0x004011d0 in mtga (+0x11cf) (0x0032ff20)
  12 0x7b451b12 call_process_entry+0x11() in kernel32 (0x0032ff38)
  13 0x7b451ca3 start_process+0x152() in kernel32 (0x0032ffdc)
  14 0x7b451b2a start_process_wrapper+0x9() in kernel32 (0x0032ffec)
0x7bc4c488 stub_entry_point+0x48 in ntdll: subl $4,%esp
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (293 modules)
PE    400000-  4a1000   Export          mtga
PE   1dd0000- 21f5000   Deferred        mono-2.0-bdwgc
PE  10000000-1115a000   Export          unityplayer
PE  40001000-401b6000   Deferred        libwine.1.0.dylib
ELF 401e7000-401ff000   Deferred        hid<elf>
  \-PE  401f0000-401fd000   \               hid
ELF 41d86000-41da0000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  41d90000-41d9e000   \               version
ELF 41da0000-41dcb000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  41db0000-41dc7000   \               msacm32
ELF 41dcb000-41df0000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  41dd0000-41deb000   \               imm32
ELF 44988000-44b9a000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  44990000-44b71000   \               user32
ELF 44b9a000-44ccd000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  44ba0000-44cb4000   \               gdi32
ELF 44ccd000-44d4c000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  44cd0000-44d33000   \               advapi32
ELF 44d4c000-44eab000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  44d50000-44e6d000   \               ole32
ELF 44eab000-44f3c000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  44eb0000-44f1a000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 44f3c000-44fc3000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  44f40000-44f9e000   \               shlwapi
ELF 44fc3000-45046000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  44fd0000-45023000   \               setupapi
ELF 45046000-45a23000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  45050000-459d4000   \               shell32
ELF 45a23000-45ae3000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  45a30000-45ad5000   \               winmm
ELF 45ae3000-45b23000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  45af0000-45b1d000   \               ws2_32
ELF 45b23000-45c5b000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  45b30000-45c25000   \               oleaut32
ELF 45c5b000-45c7d000   Deferred        dnsapi<elf>
  \-PE  45c60000-45c78000   \               dnsapi
ELF 45c7d000-45cb4000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  45c80000-45ca9000   \               netapi32
ELF 45cb4000-45cde000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  45cc0000-45cd8000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 45cde000-45d29000   Deferred        winhttp<elf>
  \-PE  45ce0000-45d16000   \               winhttp
ELF 45d29000-45d53000   Deferred        jsproxy<elf>
  \-PE  45d30000-45d45000   \               jsproxy
PE  45d53000-45ddc000   Deferred        libfreetype.6.dylib
ELF 45ddc000-45df0000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0<elf>
  \-PE  45de0000-45def000   \               api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
ELF 45df0000-45e04000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1<elf>
  \-PE  45e00000-45e03000   \               api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
ELF 45e04000-45e18000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1<elf>
  \-PE  45e10000-45e17000   \               api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1
ELF 45e18000-45e2c000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1<elf>
  \-PE  45e20000-45e2b000   \               api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1
ELF 45e2c000-45e40000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  45e30000-45e3f000   \               api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0
ELF 45e40000-45e75000   Deferred        combase<elf>
  \-PE  45e50000-45e62000   \               combase
ELF 45e75000-45e8a000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-1<elf>
  \-PE  45e80000-45e89000   \               api-ms-win-core-com-l1-1-1
ELF 45e8a000-45e9e000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0<elf>
  \-PE  45e90000-45e9d000   \               api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0
ELF 45e9e000-45f4e000   Deferred        winemac<elf>
  \-PE  45ea0000-45f24000   \               winemac
ELF 464a0000-464b5000   Deferred        mswsock<elf>
  \-PE  464b0000-464b3000   \               mswsock
ELF 464b5000-464c9000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  464c0000-464c8000   \               psapi
ELF 464c9000-464dd000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-1<elf>
  \-PE  464d0000-464dc000   \               api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-1
PE  464dd000-46504000   Deferred        libpng15.15.dylib
ELF 4652a000-46543000   Deferred        shcore<elf>
  \-PE  46530000-46540000   \               shcore
ELF 46543000-4655a000   Deferred        vulkan-1<elf>
  \-PE  46550000-46559000   \               vulkan-1
ELF 486f9000-487a8000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  48700000-48785000   \               msvcrt
PE  6a540000-6a77c000   Deferred        d3d11
PE  6f400000-6f5c2000   Export          dxgi
ELF 7a800000-7a8fe000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7a810000-7a8be000   \               opengl32
ELF 7b400000-7b7ff000   Stabs           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b410000-7b7c2000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcf6000   Stabs           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcce000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf03000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
PE  9029f000-902a0000   Deferred        accelerate
PE  902b7000-909f9000   Deferred        vimage
PE  909f9000-90b34000   Deferred        libblas.dylib
PE  90b34000-90b62000   Deferred        libbnns.dylib
PE  90b62000-90ed6000   Deferred        liblapack.dylib
PE  90ed6000-90eed000   Deferred        liblinearalgebra.dylib
PE  90eed000-90f07000   Deferred        libsparseblas.dylib
PE  90f07000-91067000   Deferred        libvdsp.dylib
PE  91067000-91148000   Deferred        libvmisc.dylib
PE  91148000-91149000   Deferred        veclib
PE  9133c000-920ff000   Deferred        appkit
PE  92150000-92151000   Deferred        applicationservices
PE  92151000-921b8000   Deferred        ats
PE  921ba000-922df000   Deferred        libfontparser.dylib
PE  922df000-9232c000   Deferred        libfontregistry.dylib
PE  9237a000-923ae000   Deferred        libtruetypescaler.dylib
PE  92419000-9241f000   Deferred        colorsynclegacy
PE  924c8000-92521000   Deferred        hiservices
PE  92521000-92531000   Deferred        langanalysis
PE  92531000-9258a000   Deferred        printcore
PE  9258a000-92621000   Deferred        qd
PE  92621000-9262e000   Deferred        speechsynthesis
PE  9262e000-9287e000   Deferred        audiotoolbox
PE  9287f000-92880000   Deferred        audiounit
PE  929b7000-92d2d000   Deferred        cfnetwork
PE  92d41000-92d42000   Deferred        carbon
PE  92d42000-92d4c000   Deferred        carbonsound
PE  92d4c000-92d51000   Deferred        commonpanels
PE  92d51000-930e8000   Deferred        hitoolbox
PE  930e8000-9313d000   Deferred        htmlrendering
PE  9313d000-93141000   Deferred        help
PE  93141000-93147000   Deferred        imagecapture
PE  93147000-931e2000   Deferred        ink
PE  931e2000-9321d000   Deferred        navigationservices
PE  9321d000-93239000   Deferred        openscripting
PE  93239000-9323f000   Deferred        print
PE  9323f000-93242000   Deferred        securityhi
PE  93242000-93249000   Deferred        speechrecognition
PE  93256000-93316000   Deferred        colorsync
PE  93316000-933b2000   Deferred        coreaudio
PE  9340f000-93415000   Deferred        corebluetooth
PE  93415000-936f8000   Deferred        coredata
PE  936f8000-936ff000   Deferred        coredisplay
PE  936ff000-93b8a000   Deferred        corefoundation
PE  93b8b000-941bf000   Deferred        coregraphics
PE  941c0000-94437000   Deferred        coreimage
PE  9463e000-9463f000   Deferred        coreservices
PE  9463f000-946b2000   Deferred        ae
PE  946b2000-94991000   Deferred        carboncore
PE  94991000-949c6000   Deferred        dictionaryservices
PE  949c6000-949cf000   Deferred        fsevents
PE  949cf000-94b2f000   Deferred        launchservices
PE  94b2f000-94bdd000   Deferred        metadata
PE  94bdd000-94c3f000   Deferred        osservices
PE  94c3f000-94cb1000   Deferred        searchkit
PE  94cb1000-94cd5000   Deferred        sharedfilelist
PE  94cd5000-94e23000   Deferred        coretext
PE  94e23000-94e5e000   Deferred        corevideo
PE  94e5e000-94ee6000   Deferred        corewlan
PE  95139000-95143000   Deferred        diskarbitration
PE  95153000-954c4000   Deferred        foundation
PE  95504000-95534000   Deferred        gss
PE  95560000-95679000   Deferred        iobluetooth
PE  956de000-95780000   Deferred        iokit
PE  95781000-95789000   Deferred        iosurface
PE  957dd000-95962000   Deferred        imageio
PE  95962000-95967000   Deferred        libgif.dylib
PE  95967000-95a59000   Deferred        libjp2.dylib
PE  95a59000-95a7c000   Deferred        libjpeg.dylib
PE  95a7c000-95aa3000   Deferred        libpng.dylib
PE  95aa3000-95aa6000   Deferred        libradiance.dylib
PE  95aa6000-95af1000   Deferred        libtiff.dylib
PE  964fc000-96515000   Deferred        kerberos
PE  96bd6000-96c4f000   Deferred        metal
PE  96c50000-96c5d000   Deferred        netfs
PE  99592000-995eb000   Deferred        opencl
PE  995eb000-99608000   Deferred        cfopendirectory
PE  99608000-99614000   Deferred        opendirectory
PE  9a81d000-9a81f000   Deferred        libcvmspluginsupport.dylib
PE  9a81f000-9a824000   Deferred        libcorefscache.dylib
PE  9a824000-9a829000   Deferred        libcorevmclient.dylib
PE  9a829000-9a833000   Deferred        libgfxshared.dylib
PE  9a833000-9a840000   Deferred        libgl.dylib
PE  9a840000-9a87c000   Deferred        libglimage.dylib
PE  9a9f5000-9aa38000   Deferred        libglu.dylib
PE  9b3de000-9b3ee000   Deferred        opengl
PE  9c15a000-9c395000   Deferred        quartzcore
PE  9c829000-9cb5d000   Deferred        security
PE  9cb5d000-9cbe6000   Deferred        securityfoundation
PE  9cc11000-9cc16000   Deferred        servicemanagement
PE  9cd40000-9cdb1000   Deferred        systemconfiguration
PE  9edfa000-9ee9a000   Deferred        apfs
PE  9f4af000-9f4db000   Deferred        apple80211
PE  9f4dc000-9f4e7000   Deferred        applefscompression
PE  9f5e7000-9f625000   Deferred        applejpeg
PE  9f777000-9f77f000   Deferred        backgroundtaskmanagement
PE  9f77f000-9f80b000   Deferred        backup
PE  9f950000-9f95a000   Deferred        commonauth
PE  9fdf4000-9fe05000   Deferred        coreemoji
PE  9ff8d000-9ffc1000   Deferred        coreservicesinternal
PE  9ffc1000-a0058000   Deferred        coresymbolication
PE  a0058000-a0180000   Deferred        coreui
PE  a0180000-a021f000   Deferred        coreutils
PE  a026f000-a02cd000   Deferred        corewifi
PE  a02cd000-a02de000   Deferred        crashreportersupport
PE  a034b000-a0359000   Deferred        dfrfoundation
PE  a03a4000-a0416000   Deferred        datadetectorscore
PE  a0416000-a0457000   Deferred        debugsymbols
PE  a0457000-a0597000   Deferred        desktopservicespriv
PE  a08d6000-a0d07000   Deferred        facecore
PE  a36b8000-a372c000   Deferred        heimdal
PE  a39e3000-a39eb000   Deferred        ioaccelerator
PE  a39eb000-a3a05000   Deferred        iopresentment
PE  a3a61000-a3a82000   Deferred        iconservices
PE  a3ab9000-a3bae000   Deferred        languagemodeling
PE  a3bae000-a3bef000   Deferred        lexicon
PE  a3bf2000-a3bf9000   Deferred        linguisticdata
PE  a3f85000-a3fb0000   Deferred        multitouchsupport
PE  a40ce000-a40d9000   Deferred        netauth
PE  a4180000-a418e000   Deferred        performanceanalysis
PE  a422d000-a424a000   Deferred        protocolbuffer
PE  a4338000-a435b000   Deferred        remoteviewservices
PE  a4402000-a4430000   Deferred        sharing
PE  a444e000-a4450000   Deferred        signpostnotification
PE  a4450000-a44d7000   Deferred        skylight
PE  a4506000-a4514000   Deferred        speechrecognitioncore
PE  a47e3000-a486a000   Deferred        symbolication
PE  a48bc000-a48c5000   Deferred        tcc
PE  a48c5000-a48dd000   Deferred        textureio
PE  a490b000-a4a96000   Deferred        uifoundation
PE  a5064000-a5067000   Deferred        loginsupport
PE  a50f1000-a5125000   Deferred        libclosured.dylib
PE  a5180000-a51b8000   Deferred        libcrfsuite.dylib
PE  a51b8000-a51c3000   Deferred        libchinesetokenizer.dylib
PE  a525e000-a5260000   Deferred        libdiagnosticmessagesclient.dylib
PE  a5291000-a547c000   Deferred        libfosl_dynamic.dylib
PE  a5483000-a5484000   Deferred        libopenscriptingutil.dylib
PE  a54d7000-a54dc000   Deferred        libscreenreader.dylib
PE  a54dc000-a54de000   Deferred        libsystem.b.dylib
PE  a54ec000-a5502000   Deferred        libapple_nghttp2.dylib
PE  a5502000-a552e000   Deferred        libarchive.2.dylib
PE  a552e000-a567e000   Deferred        libate.dylib
PE  a5681000-a5682000   Deferred        libauto.dylib
PE  a5682000-a5693000   Deferred        libbsm.0.dylib
PE  a5693000-a56a0000   Deferred        libbz2.1.0.dylib
PE  a56a0000-a56fa000   Deferred        libc++.1.dylib
PE  a56fa000-a571c000   Deferred        libc++abi.dylib
PE  a571d000-a572f000   Deferred        libcmph.dylib
PE  a572f000-a5745000   Deferred        libcompression.dylib
PE  a5745000-a575d000   Deferred        libcoretls.dylib
PE  a575d000-a575f000   Deferred        libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib
PE  a5c46000-a5c9e000   Deferred        libcups.2.dylib
PE  a5db4000-a5db5000   Deferred        libenergytrace.dylib
PE  a5de8000-a5ded000   Deferred        libheimdal-asn1.dylib
PE  a5e18000-a5f09000   Deferred        libiconv.2.dylib
PE  a5f09000-a612c000   Deferred        libicucore.a.dylib
PE  a6173000-a6175000   Deferred        liblangid.dylib
PE  a6175000-a618e000   Deferred        liblzma.5.dylib
PE  a618e000-a61a4000   Deferred        libmarisa.dylib
PE  a6258000-a6476000   Deferred        libmecabra.dylib
PE  a647a000-a64aa000   Deferred        libncurses.5.4.dylib
PE  a663c000-a67b4000   Deferred        libnetwork.dylib
PE  a67b4000-a6b95000   Deferred        libobjc.a.dylib
PE  a6b98000-a6b9c000   Deferred        libpam.2.dylib
PE  a6b9e000-a6bd0000   Deferred        libpcap.a.dylib
PE  a6c0d000-a6c29000   Deferred        libresolv.9.dylib
PE  a6c73000-a6dfe000   Deferred        libsqlite3.dylib
PE  a6fa1000-a7001000   Deferred        libusrtcp.dylib
PE  a7001000-a7005000   Deferred        libutil.dylib
PE  a7005000-a7014000   Deferred        libxar.1.dylib
PE  a7014000-a70f3000   Deferred        libxml2.2.dylib
PE  a70f3000-a711c000   Deferred        libxslt.1.dylib
PE  a711c000-a712c000   Deferred        libz.1.dylib
PE  a7166000-a716b000   Deferred        libcache.dylib
PE  a716b000-a7176000   Deferred        libcommoncrypto.dylib
PE  a7176000-a717c000   Deferred        libcompiler_rt.dylib
PE  a717c000-a7187000   Deferred        libcopyfile.dylib
PE  a7187000-a71f0000   Deferred        libcorecrypto.dylib
PE  a725a000-a7290000   Deferred        libdispatch.dylib
PE  a7290000-a72ae000   Deferred        libdyld.dylib
PE  a72ae000-a72af000   Deferred        libkeymgr.dylib
PE  a72af000-a72bc000   Deferred        libkxld.dylib
PE  a72bc000-a72bd000   Deferred        liblaunch.dylib
PE  a72bd000-a72c3000   Deferred        libmacho.dylib
PE  a72c3000-a72c6000   Deferred        libquarantine.dylib
PE  a72c6000-a72c8000   Deferred        libremovefile.dylib
PE  a72c8000-a72e0000   Deferred        libsystem_asl.dylib
PE  a72e0000-a72e1000   Deferred        libsystem_blocks.dylib
PE  a72e1000-a736e000   Deferred        libsystem_c.dylib
PE  a736e000-a7372000   Deferred        libsystem_configuration.dylib
PE  a7372000-a7376000   Deferred        libsystem_coreservices.dylib
PE  a7376000-a7378000   Deferred        libsystem_darwin.dylib
PE  a7378000-a737f000   Deferred        libsystem_dnssd.dylib
PE  a737f000-a73cf000   Deferred        libsystem_info.dylib
PE  a73cf000-a73f4000   Deferred        libsystem_kernel.dylib
PE  a73f4000-a7444000   Deferred        libsystem_m.dylib
PE  a7444000-a745f000   Deferred        libsystem_malloc.dylib
PE  a745f000-a7584000   Deferred        libsystem_network.dylib
PE  a7584000-a758f000   Deferred        libsystem_networkextension.dylib
PE  a758f000-a7598000   Deferred        libsystem_notify.dylib
PE  a7598000-a759f000   Deferred        libsystem_platform.dylib
PE  a759f000-a75aa000   Deferred        libsystem_pthread.dylib
PE  a75aa000-a75ae000   Deferred        libsystem_sandbox.dylib
PE  a75ae000-a75b1000   Deferred        libsystem_secinit.dylib
PE  a75b1000-a75ba000   Deferred        libsystem_symptoms.dylib
PE  a75ba000-a75cd000   Deferred        libsystem_trace.dylib
PE  a75ce000-a75d5000   Deferred        libunwind.dylib
PE  a75d5000-a75ff000   Deferred        libxpc.dylib
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Wizards of the Coast\MTGA\MTGA.exe
    00000032    0
    00000031   -1
    00000030    0
    00000009    0 <==
0000000e services.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001b    0
    00000013    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 winedevice.exe
    00000018    0
    00000017    0
    00000016    0
    00000012    0
00000019 plugplay.exe
    0000001d    0
    0000001c    0
    0000001a    0
0000001e winedevice.exe
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000025    0
    00000022    0
    00000021    0
    0000001f    0
00000023 explorer.exe
    0000002d    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0
    00000024    0
0000002e UnityCrashHandler32.exe
    00000033    0
    0000002f    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-3.18
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 10
    Host system: Darwin
    Host version: 17.7.0
```

And I'm stuck again.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am running into the same issues on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) using OS Mojave.

Comment: @JoelCave: see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I've found so far is the installation process described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MagicArena/comments/95rgko/a_guide_to_run_mtg_arena_with_wine_on_osx/). It essentially uses the same tools (i.e., Wine), but it works! (No idea which is the difference. If someone knows, please let me know, I'm curious).

N.B.: after the initial installation, the first time you launch the program it will download many packages. If during the download the program crashes don't worry, just use `Cmd+Tab` to switch back to your desktop and close the app from the dock (use right-click) and relaunch it. Iterate this process until all packages have been downloaded. Enjoy!

Comment: That's the post I used to get it working on my iMac, but can't get it to work on my MacBook for some reason. Probably just as well. I'm too addicted as it is.